# Self-energy of a fermion system with critical hybridization?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fermions, mean-field-theory

Consider the following Hamiltonian, with two species of fermions ($c$ and $f$) and only inter-species local interactions:
$$ H = \sum_k \epsilon_k c_k^\dagger c_k + \sum_q \varepsilon_q f_q^\dagger f_q + \sum_i V c_i^\dagger c_i f_i^\dagger f_i.$$
I could define a mean-field parameter $\langle b \rangle = \langle{c_i^\dagger f_i}\rangle$ and decompose the Hamiltonian in this hybridization channel. The mean-field interaction term then looks like
$$V_{int}^{MF} = \sum_i V \left( \langle b \rangle f_i^\dagger c_i + \langle b^\dagger \rangle c_i^\dagger f_i  -\langle b \rangle\langle b^\dagger \rangle \right).$$
My question is: **right at the critical point, where $\langle b \rangle = 0$ but $\langle b^2 \rangle \neq 0$ or $\langle b b^\dagger \rangle \neq 0$, how do I compute the self-energy contribution to the $c$ fermions?**

Is it correct to do the following? Treat $b = c_i^\dagger f_i$ as one object, so that diagrammatically, the lowest-order contribution to the self-energy will look like $D_{b} G_f$ for $D_b$ the "propagator" of $b$ and $G_f$ the $f$ Green function? Then, I will have a factor of $\langle c_i^\dagger f_i f_i^\dagger c_i\rangle $. Should I then evaluate the expectation $\langle c_i^\dagger f_i f_i^\dagger c_i\rangle$ in mean-field?